# Access a third party server with SSH key from GCP function

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions, serverless

I need to upload files to a third party server that has only SSH key based authantication. I can successfully connect using a VM where I have the SSH key which has been added to known hosts by the said third party server.

However, it's lot more practical to use a short lived function which nicely integrates with storage events. I am strugling to find a way to include the SSH key for authantication inside functions on GCP.

Any help appriciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You could be using the [GCP Secret Manager](https://cloud.google.com/secret-manager) for instance.

**The lifecycle:**

1. put the key to the Secret Manager once, and
2. keep reusing it from your function.

**SSH / Scp Client - Working around known hosts:**

The client side needs to add the ssh parameters while connecting:

```
-o UserKnownHostsFile=/dev/null -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no -o
```

**CAUTION:**

Please keep in mind that by doing so you are turning off adding the machine to known hosts, and the built-in man in the middle attack check. Please take into consideration that it's "bad practice" and that you need to be sure that your code is connecting to the right server, as you now have no chance to figure it out during connection establishing.

**The Secret Manager client:**

> function which nicely integrates with storage events

depending on the technology you are going to implement this in, you could be checking [this client libraries documentation.](https://cloud.google.com/secret-manager/docs/reference/libraries) for several languages.